# Overflow VISIBLE like foursquare.com on the map

Tags: html, css, google-maps, overflow, foursquare

If you check foursquare.com you can see they have an active map on right side of screen, but this map overflow: visible to the full screen. I want to get same result with Google Maps if possible, have a container with defined size but yet overflow it on whole screen.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can set the Google Maps iframe inline width and height in percent. Why not create a div that fills the area you want the map in, then set width="100%" and height="100%" on the iframe?